# WPF version of VirtualScreen

Tags: wpf, virtual-screen

Is there a WPF version of System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VirtualScreen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is. `System.Windows.SystemParameters` (in the PresentationFramework assembly) has a number of static VirtualScreen properties: `VirtualScreenHeight`, `VirtualScreenWidth`, `VirtualScreenLeft`, and `VirtualScreenTop`. It also has properties of the same names with 'Key' appended that return `ResourceKey`s.

Found using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).